# Famous examples of PhD advisors younger than their student

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, big-list

What are the most famous examples of PhD advisors in mathematics, younger than their student?
(if possible put the date of birth and/or the difference in age).

Comment: Does Whitfield Diffie count? He was more than a year older than his advisor Martin Hellman. (Un)fortunately he never finished his degree. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitfield_Diffie

Comment: @ThiKu: But he still has a doctorate, though.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svetlana_Katok appears to be older than her advisor http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Zagier. I didn't go through all of Zagier's students, but there could be more examples among the early ones.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a research level math question, and is therefore not on-topic for MO. I would vote to close but I can't.

Comment: I think this phenomenon is fairly common. For example, I am younger than one of my PhD students, and my advisor is younger than at least one of his PhD students. It often happens that a person pursues the PhD later in life, after other accomplishments, and in such a case they can easily find themselves with a younger advisor. But I would rather that we should be discussing mathematician's theorems on MO, rather than their ages.

Comment: Let me add that in the cases with which I am familiar, the advisor/student relation was not fundamentally affected by the difference in age; it was just like normal.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Advisors early in life seems more uncommon than students later in life. Anyway, this post is a recreation between two theorems.

Comment: I believe that the late-student phenomenon could be less unusual in the U.S. than in Europe.

Comment: Also, it seems to me to be probably true that one is more likely to find a young professor serving as a Ph.D. supervisor in the U.S. than in Europe. (But I recognise, @SébastienPalcoux, that you are not currently in Europe.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: I believe you're right, the research establishment in France (and perhaps in all the E.U.), seems more rigid than in the U.S. or in India.  I hope this will change.

Answer (score 14):

The only example I know is Charlie Fefferman and his first student.

*Advisor*: Fefferman, born April 18, 1949.  Year of PhD 1969.
*Student*: [Antonio Córdoba Barba](http://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=6690), born January 12, 1949. Year of PhD 1974.

Difference in age: 3 months and change.

---

Trivia: that is the only example I know also where both father and [son](http://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=83675) studied under the same PhD advisor.

Comment: Though I wouldn't be surprised at more examples considering http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3591/mathematicians-who-were-late-learners-list http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7120/too-old-for-advanced-mathematics and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43341/technical-phd-after-33

Comment: John Fogarty was older than his adviser David Mumford.

Comment: Anders Björner *simultaneously* had both father and son as students: Henrik and Kimmo Eriksson.